# Duplicate name when using .htaccess to remove .php

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following commands in my .htaccess file to remove the .php extension from the url on my pages. The code used was found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588022/htaccess-to-remove-php-extension-godaddy) question.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

When I test this by typing mydomain.com/page into my browser it duplicates my domain name and returns mydomain.com/mydomain/page which ultimately returns a 404 error.  What am I doing wrong? If it helps, site is hosted on Hostmonster.com.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply reprocessing the rule over and over (because it still matches both of the RewriteConds, even after the rule has been applied)

So, you'd just need to put in a 'negative match' on the REQUEST_URI, and then an [L] at the RewriteRule, just to be sure.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

hth

Comment: Thanks for replying but I am still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting just mydomain repeated rather than mydomain.com my gut feeling is that it's something to do with the hosting.